# How to get the current path in Nautilus using the nautilus-extension Rust crate

Tags: ubuntu, rust, nautilus

I'm fairly new to rust and linux and not at all familiar with the nautilus under the hood.I know the original library is written in c but I'm currently trying to focus on getting things done with rust. As the title says, I'm trying to get the current directory in a nautilus instance statically and after a navigation is done. Is it possible? Or maybe there's even a better way of doing that than with the nautilus-extension package?